# How to get returned value in generic function?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Please look at code sample:

```
fun <T> query(sql: String, params: JsonArray): T? {
    val row = otherfun(sql, params) 
    return row.mapTo(T)
}
```

How to pass in mapTo(Class klz) function (It's java function) proper argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your function [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) (and therefore `inline`), and then you can use [`::class.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass) to get a `Class`instance:

```
inline fun <reified T> query(sql: String, params: JsonArray): T? {
    val row = otherfun(sql, params)
    return row.mapTo(T::class.java)
}
```